# what is the relationship of thread and task?

Tags: java, oop

I know that Thread and Task are in different abstraction-level.But anyway,I'm still confused that what's the relationship of them.And,by the way,I think that the Task tells how to do a job and the Thread actually excute the job according to  a Task instance.Is my understanding correct?thank u^

Comment: What is Task?  Is it java class?

Comment: There is nothing as a `Task` in java's core API. Can you please specify to what you are referring to?

Comment: I'd guess it's about [`java.util.concurrent.FutureTask`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) as discussed in [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412491/whether-method-cancel-and-method-interrupt-do-the-duplicate-job/7412704#7412704)

Comment: yes.And my understanding,they do the same job right there, is correct or not?thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by *Task* you mean `Runnable` and `Callable`. The relationship is simple:

> Thread *might* be used to execute *multiple* tasks

- *might* - because you don't need a separate thread to execute tasks (well, technically, everything runs inside a thread - you don't need a separate one)
- *multiple* - thread can be reused; it can run multiple tasks from a collection like queue

Typically one thread executes one `Runnable` passed to `Thread` constructor or multiple `Callable`s passed to `ExecutorService` (wrapping thread pool in most cases).

Comment: thank u.I got ur meaning.And I have a further question like:I read the source of org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseUtil.runParser(Parser p, Content content).

Do these two method calls do the same thing:

Instruction 1:

t.interrupt();
Instruction 2:

task.cancel(true);

Comment: Please post it as a separate question

Comment: Tomas: he [already did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412491/whether-method-cancel-and-method-interrupt-do-the-duplicate-job/7412704#7412704) ... 1 hour ago.

Answer (score 0):

If by `Task` you mean something like [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html), then the difference is that the task is used to run some thread-like code execution, but has additional properties, such as when to run it, how many times, and the option to cancel its execution, whereas a thread will just go ahead and run once immediately.

Answer (score 0):

A task is rather abstract it can be implemented as a process or a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.

We can do the analogy with [workflow patterns](http://www.workflowpatterns.com/patterns/) where tasks are something that needs to be done in a process and threads are resources used to process or execute them.